# How to link JPA persistence context with single database transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions, spring-data-jpa

Latest Spring Boot with JPA and Hibernate: I'm struggling to understand the relationship between transactions, the persistence context and the hibernate session and I can't easily avoid the dreaded no session lazy initialization problem.

I update a set of objects in one transaction and then I want to loop through those objects processing them each in a separate transaction - seems straightforward.

```
public void control() {
    List<> entities = getEntitiesToProcess();
    for (Entity entity : entities) {
        processEntity(entity.getId());
    }
}

@Transactional(value=TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public List<Entity> getEntitiesToProcess() {
    List<Entity> entities = entityRepository.findAll();
    for (Entity entity : entities) {
        // Update a few properties
    }
    return entities;
}

@Transactional(value=TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void processEntity(String id) {
    Entity entity = entityRepository.getOne(id);
    entity.getLazyInitialisedListOfObjects(); // throws LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
}
```

However, I get a problem because (I think) the same hibernate session is being used for both transactions.  When I call entityRepository.getOne(id) in the 2nd transaction, I can see in the debugger that I am returned exactly the same object that was returned by findAll() in the 1st transaction without a DB access.  If I understand this correctly, it's the hibernate cache doing this?  If I then call a method on my object that requires a lazy evaluation, I get a "no session" error.  I thought the cache and the session were linked so that's my first confusion.

If I drop all the @Transactional annotations or if I put a @Transactional on the control method it all runs fine, but the database commit isn't done until the control method completes which is obviously not what I want.

So, I have a few questions:

1. How can I make the hibernate session align with my transaction scope?
2. What is a good pattern for doing the separation transactions in a loop with JPA and declarative transaction management?

I want to retain the declarative style (i.e. no xml), and don't want to do anything Hibernate specific.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks

Marcus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring creates a proxy around your service class, which means `@Transactional` annotations are only applied when annotated methods are called through the proxy (where you have injected this service).

You are calling `getEntitiesToProcess()` and `processEntity()` from within `control()`, which means those calls are not going through proxy but instead have the transactional scope of the `control()` method (if you aren't also calling `control()` from another method in the same class).

In order for `@Transactional` to apply, you need to do something like this

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

public void control() {
    MyService myService = applicationContext.getBean(MyService.class);
    List<> entities = myService.getEntitiesToProcess();
    for (Entity entity : entities) {
        myService.processEntity(entity.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: Grrgh.  How frustrating!  I was looking in entirely the wrong place, and whilst I did know all about the proxies and the transaction interceptor I was so distracted by the session message I failed to notice the transactions weren't working properly!  Thanks, much appreciated.